# In JqxGrid inline edit how to change text to uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I have  jqxGrid, in the case of inline edit I want to transform user input to uppercase letter if it is in lowercase letter. I tried cellbeginedit, rowclick and rowdoubleclick event but it is too early , input text box comes after this even.

I have also tried cellvaluechangeevent , it get fired when use move out of the cells.

I want listener/function which will be fired when user enter data in input box.
or I want the event when input box is created so  I can change its css 'text-transform' to 'uppercase'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use angular modelController and formatter with a directive. Here is one example implementation - https://evoyan.org/angularjs-directive-uppercase-input/